# PHP almacenar archivo pdf por type="file" en una sola variable php

Tags: php, phpmailer

estoy intentando enviar un archivo adjunto a un correo, la verdad funciona si llamo directamente al archivo desde una variable php por ejemplo: `$archivo='archivo.pdf'`
pero por obvias razones necesito usar un input file para buscar mi archivo en especifico, pero para almacenar un archivo necesito del metodo `$_FILE` y descomponer el archivo en cuatro partes, todo bien hasta ahi, mi problema es cuando trato de adjuntar la variable `$_FILE` a el metodo `AddAttachment()` porque este necesita que la varible sea unica y no como un array, entonces quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que la variable `$_FILE` pueda leerse en el metodo `AddAttachment()`  o si puedo hacer que en una sola variable php pueda juntar el archivo descompuesto y asi hacer funcionar el metodo `AddAttachment()`.
mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
        <?php include "class.phpmailer.php";
    include "class.smtp.php";
    $email_user = $_POST["correo"];
    $email_password = $_POST["pass"];
    $the_subject = $_POST["asunto"];
    $address_to = $_POST["remitente"];
    $from_name = $_POST["nombre"];
    //el metodo file descompuesto
    $nameFile = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $sizeFile = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
    $typeFile = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
    $tempFile = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
    //un documento que copie a la ruta de mi codigo
    $archivo = "document.pdf"
    $phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
    // ---------- datos de la cuenta de Gmail -------------------------------
    $phpmailer->Username = $email_user;
    $phpmailer->Password = $email_password; 
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // $phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $phpmailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // GMail
    $phpmailer->Port = 465;
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP(); // use SMTP
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpmailer->setFrom($phpmailer->Username,$from_name);
    $phpmailer->AddAddress($address_to); // recipients email
    $phpmailer->Subject = $the_subject; 
    $phpmailer->Body .="<h1 style='color:#3498db;'>UNIVERSIDAD DICE:</h1>";
    $phpmailer->Body .= $_POST["comentario"];
    $phpmailer->Body .= "<p>Fecha y Hora: ".date("d-m-Y h:i:s")."</p>";
    $phpmailer->AddAttachment($archivo);
    $phpmailer->IsHTML(true);
    $phpmailer->Send(); ?>
```

Comment: No es necesario que copies el archivo a tu directorio, puedes usar `$phpmailer->AddAttachment($_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"]);`. Por cierto, te falta un punto y coma en: `$archivo = "document.pdf";`.

Comment: gracias, no note lo de punto y coma, pero al enviar solo el "tmp_name" me envia a mi correo un archivo php en lugar del pdf que seleccioné en el input file

Comment: ya lo solucioné, resulta que tenia que enviar el tmp y el name en el addAttachment para que el archivo pudiera enviarse

Comment: Enhorabuena. Me alegra haber sido un poco de ayuda :)